# Mongoose middleware access other collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using 'pre' 'save' middleware to create for a 'user' document a corresponding 'userObjects' document.

So there is `users` collections and `userObjects`.
And when new `user` is inserted a `userObjects` document should be inserted too.

I am trying to use the 'pre' middleware, somehow like this :

```
//before inserting a new user
Users.pre('save', function(next) {
    var UserObjects = db.model('userObjects');

    userObjectsIns = new UserObjects({
         'userID': this._id,
         'myObjects':[],
    });

    userObjectsIns.save( function(err) {
        if (err) console.log("ERROR while saving userObjectsIns: " + err);
        next()
    })        
});
```

The obvious problem, is that `db` doesn't exists. How can I reach 'userObjects' collection from within this `pre` middleware?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access other models via the [`model`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-model) method of the `this` doc instance:

```
Users.pre('save', function(next) {
    var UserObjects = this.model('userObjects');

    userObjectsIns = new UserObjects({
         'userID': this._id,
         'myObjects':[],
    });

    userObjectsIns.save( function(err) {
        if (err) console.log("ERROR while saving userObjectsIns: " + err);
        next()
    })        
});
```